# Adding Service Provider to WSO2 Identity Server via file is not working

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I want to configure within the WSO2 IDS a service provider which is available from the start. To do this I followed the following instructions: [Adding a service provider](https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/setup/configuring-a-sp-and-idp-using-configuration-files/#adding-a-service-provider)

However when i boot the IDS and attempt to initiate a call to retrieve a token I get the following response:

```
{
    "error_description": "A valid OAuth client could not be found for client_id: service-provider-fuga",
    "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

and the log within the terminal of WSO2 IDS shows the following:

```
[2021-08-05 14:06:55,111] [0d5f9d6c-5f87-4dc3-a87f-cb473cd4127c] DEBUG {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service} - Error while finding application state for application with client_id: 1ou1fLDyFA9BEqywVtrR6vAxc48a org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.common.exception.InvalidOAuthClientException: Cannot find an application associated with the given consumer key : 1ou1fLDyFA9BEqywVtrR6vAxc48a
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.dao.OAuthAppDAO.handleRequestForANonExistingConsumerKey(OAuthAppDAO.java:1154)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.dao.OAuthAppDAO.getAppInformation(OAuthAppDAO.java:354)
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.util.OAuth2Util.getAppInformationByClientId(OAuth2Util.java:1887)
```

The request I initiated is as follows: `https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&client_id=service-provider-fuga&client_secret=...&username=user&password=...`

The service provider file which is put in `/home/wso2carbon/wso2-config-volume/repository/conf/identity/service-providers/service-provider.xml` is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceProvider>
    <ApplicationName>service-provider-fuga</ApplicationName>
    <Description>Service Provider configuration for FUGA</Description>
    <JwksUri/>
    <InboundAuthenticationConfig>
        <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfigs>
            <InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
                <InboundAuthKey>1ou1fLDyFA9BEqywVtrR6vAxc48a</InboundAuthKey>
                <InboundAuthType>oauth2</InboundAuthType>
                <InboundConfigType>standardAPP</InboundConfigType>
                <inboundConfiguration><![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<oAuthAppDO>
    <oauthConsumerKey>1ou1fLDyFA9BEqywVtrR6vAxc48a</oauthConsumerKey>
    <oauthConsumerSecret>...</oauthConsumerSecret>
    <applicationName>service-provider-fuga</applicationName>
    <callbackUrl></callbackUrl>
    <oauthVersion>OAuth-2.0</oauthVersion>
    <grantTypes>refresh_token password </grantTypes>
    <scopeValidators/>
    <pkceSupportPlain>true</pkceSupportPlain>
    <pkceMandatory>false</pkceMandatory>
    <state>ACTIVE</state>
    <userAccessTokenExpiryTime>3600</userAccessTokenExpiryTime>
    <applicationAccessTokenExpiryTime>3600</applicationAccessTokenExpiryTime>
    <refreshTokenExpiryTime>86400</refreshTokenExpiryTime>
    <idTokenExpiryTime>3600</idTokenExpiryTime>
    <audiences/>
    <bypassClientCredentials>true</bypassClientCredentials>
    <renewRefreshTokenEnabled>true</renewRefreshTokenEnabled>
    <requestObjectSignatureValidationEnabled>false</requestObjectSignatureValidationEnabled>
    <idTokenEncryptionEnabled>false</idTokenEncryptionEnabled>
    <idTokenEncryptionAlgorithm>null</idTokenEncryptionAlgorithm>
    <idTokenEncryptionMethod>null</idTokenEncryptionMethod>
    <tokenType>JWT</tokenType>
</oAuthAppDO>
]]></inboundConfiguration>
                <Properties/>
            </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfig>
        </InboundAuthenticationRequestConfigs>
    </InboundAuthenticationConfig>
    <LocalAndOutBoundAuthenticationConfig>
        <AuthenticationSteps>
            <AuthenticationStep>
                <StepOrder>1</StepOrder>
                <LocalAuthenticatorConfigs>
                    <LocalAuthenticatorConfig>
                        <Name>FugaAuthenticator</Name>
                        <DisplayName>FUGA Authenticator</DisplayName>
                        <IsEnabled>true</IsEnabled>
                        <Properties/>
                    </LocalAuthenticatorConfig>
                </LocalAuthenticatorConfigs>
                <FederatedIdentityProviders/>
                <SubjectStep>false</SubjectStep>
                <AttributeStep>false</AttributeStep>
            </AuthenticationStep>
        </AuthenticationSteps>
        <AuthenticationType>local</AuthenticationType>
        <alwaysSendBackAuthenticatedListOfIdPs>false</alwaysSendBackAuthenticatedListOfIdPs>
        <UseTenantDomainInUsername>false</UseTenantDomainInUsername>
        <UseUserstoreDomainInRoles>true</UseUserstoreDomainInRoles>
        <UseUserstoreDomainInUsername>false</UseUserstoreDomainInUsername>
        <SkipConsent>false</SkipConsent>
        <skipLogoutConsent>false</skipLogoutConsent>
        <EnableAuthorization>false</EnableAuthorization>
    </LocalAndOutBoundAuthenticationConfig>
    <RequestPathAuthenticatorConfigs/>
    <InboundProvisioningConfig>
        <ProvisioningUserStore/>
        <IsProvisioningEnabled>false</IsProvisioningEnabled>
        <IsDumbModeEnabled>false</IsDumbModeEnabled>
    </InboundProvisioningConfig>
    <OutboundProvisioningConfig>
        <ProvisioningIdentityProviders/>
    </OutboundProvisioningConfig>
    <ClaimConfig>
        <RoleClaimURI/>
        <LocalClaimDialect>true</LocalClaimDialect>
        <IdpClaim/>
        <ClaimMappings/>
        <AlwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>false</AlwaysSendMappedLocalSubjectId>
        <SPClaimDialects/>
    </ClaimConfig>
    <PermissionAndRoleConfig>
        <Permissions/>
        <RoleMappings/>
        <IdpRoles/>
    </PermissionAndRoleConfig>
    <IsSaaSApp>true</IsSaaSApp>
    <ImageUrl/>
    <AccessUrl/>
    <IsDiscoverable>true</IsDiscoverable>
</ServiceProvider>
```

When I attempt to upload the file manually via the management console of WSO2 IDS is get an error that the application already exists.

When I boot the IDS without the service provider flow and upload it manually the authentication request is working.

The version of WSO2 IDS on which this occurs is 5.10.

Comment: the `client_id` in the authorization request needs to having value of the consumer key (`1ou1fLDyFA9BEqywVtrR6vAxc48a`), not the app name

Comment: Within this message (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54188534/wso2-identity-server-edit-a-service-provider-that-was-in-the-repository-conf-i/54188840?r=SearchResults&s=3|15.9141#54188840) is mentioned that identity server does not support to configure `InboundAuthenticationConfig` through file. This message however applies to an old version so I'm wondering whether that is still the case

Comment: I tried both, see here the result when using consumer key: 

```{
    "error_description": "A valid OAuth client could not be found for client_id: 1ou1fLDyFA9BEqywVtrR6vAxc48a",
    "error": "invalid_client"
}```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question with the approach we took. Might be of benefit to others.

Since we are deploying the WSO2 identity server with Helm into a kubernetes environment we decided to create a job which inserts the service provider via the WSO2 management API. The created job look as follows:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-identityserver.service-provider-fuga
  labels:
    system: identity-service
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      initContainers:
        - name: wait-for-ids
          image: groundnuty/k8s-wait-for:v1.3
          args:
            - "pod"
            - "-ldeployment=identityserver"
      containers:
        - name: import-service-provider-fuga
          image: curlimages/curl:7.72.0
          args:
          - /bin/sh
          - -ec
          - "curl --location --request POST 'http://{{ .Release.Name }}-identityserver-service:9763/api/server/v1/applications/import' --header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46c3VwZXJTZWNyZXQ=' --form 'file=@\"/service-provider.xml\"'"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: identity-server-conf
              mountPath: /service-provider.xml
              subPath: service-provider.xml
      volumes:
        - name: identity-server-conf
          configMap:
            name: {{ .Release.Name }}-identityserver.cm
```

The `wait-for-ids` container makes the job wait until all IDS pods are running. The central part of the job calls the IDS management API to import the service provider. The service provider xml file is stored within a configuration map.

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 IS does not support adding the OAuth application configuration through file inside `/repository/conf/identity/service-providers/`. Because for the oAuth application, we need the entries in the database to manage the tokens issued for the applications. So file-based storage will not work for OAuth applications.

> When I attempt to upload the file manually via the management console
> of WSO2 IDS is get an error that the application already exists.

This is kind of expected, even though WSO2 IS does not support OAuth applications from file-based configuration. Having the file in `/repository/conf/identity/service-providers/` will be considered as an application in the system (because WSO2 IS support multiple inbound protocols for same application - SAML or OAuth)

Comment: Are there alternatives to create the service provider at bootup of WSO IDS? We are using the docker/kubernetes for deployment and would like to have it as automated as possible. Also for applying the integration tests we need a instance with the service provider configured

Comment: We can write an OSGi bundle to check for the existence of this application and create this application. But this will affect the startup time of the docker/kubernetes deployment. So usually we don't recommend it in these kind of deployments. But as you should the have the permanent Database, so this will be one time task. You can have a external script(dataseeder) to populate these data to the new deployment.

Comment: Can you provide me some examples on how to create such OSGI bundle and/or which tables I need to seed. 
Update: found this documentation regarding the tables: https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/service-provider-related-tables/

Comment: I believe we used the file based configuration, but it is not well documented and we had to dig the parameter names from the source code. So later we switched to creating the SP config using the admin services

Comment: Here is an example where we create the OAuth application during the server start up https://github.com/wso2/identity-apps/blob/master/components/org.wso2.identity.apps.common/src/main/java/org/wso2/identity/apps/common/internal/AppsCommonServiceComponent.java#L75

Answer (score 0):

We have eventually added the service provider via a kubernetes job after the IDS has been booted. The job looks as follows:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-identityserver.service-provider-fuga
  labels:
    system: identity-service
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
      initContainers:
        - name: wait-for-ids
          image: groundnuty/k8s-wait-for:v1.3
          args:
            - "pod"
            - "-ldeployment=identityserver"
      containers:
        - name: import-service-provider-fuga
          image: curlimages/curl:7.72.0
          args:
          - /bin/sh
          - -ec
          - "curl --location --request POST 'http://{{ .Release.Name }}-identityserver-service:9763/api/server/v1/applications/import' --header 'Authorization: Basic {{ (printf "%s:%s" .Values.identityserver.management.admin.user .Values.identityserver.management.admin.password) | b64enc }}' --form 'file=@\"/service-provider-fuga.xml\"'"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: identity-server-conf
              mountPath: /service-provider-fuga.xml
              subPath: service-provider-fuga.xml
      volumes:
        - name: identity-server-conf
          configMap:
            name: {{ .Release.Name }}-identityserver.cm
```

The configuration of the service provider is shared via a configuration map.